# How to log all communication attempts with istio-proxy

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have istio 1.1.3 with mtls and service-registry on a kubespray k8 cluster. I want to secure all outgoing traffic, hence I create service-entries for each external service that my services want to talk to.

I would like to use istio-proxy logs to see the blocked communication attempts for all sort of traffic.

If i curl from within container to a (blocked) http://google.com i see  404 NR in istio-proxy logs. Also curl receives 404. As expected

If i change call to use https, and curl (still blocked) https://google.com, i see the following curl error
(35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to google.com:443
and nothing shows up in istio-proxy logs (why nothing?)

How can i see all connection attempts in istio-proxy? I have a pretty convoluted bunch of services that do covert-ops outgoing calls and i need to figure out what hostnames/ips/ports they are trying to hit

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can try to set different logging levels with:

```
--log_output_level <string>
```

> Comma-separated minimum per-scope logging level of messages to output,
>   in the form of :,:,... where scope can be
>   one of [all, default, model, rbac] and level can be one of [debug,
>   info, warn, error, fatal, none] (default `default:info`)

More info can be found [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/pilot-agent/)

Please let me know if that helped.